# Displaying animated data over time with the Google Maps API and JS

Tags: google-maps-api, heat-map, angularjs

I'm building an app using Google Maps API and AngularJS.
I've managed to display data both as pointers, clusters and heat maps and to reload the maps in real time when the data changes.

Now I was thinking about the possibility to actually display a dynamic/animated heatmap that, for example, given a certain array of objects with with date property, displays a heatmap that changes over time, so you see a progression.

After many google searches I haven't found anything built with Google Maps that does something similar.

Could anyone tell me if it is even possible? And if not, which technology would you recommend for such a map?

Answer (score 1):

assuming your new data are store in the newdata array
 for change  the heat map you can use

```
  heatmap.set('data', newdata)
```

so you can use a proper setInterval  or a timed function for refreshe  ..build your newdata content  and update the heatmap object